# Toggle button not to trigger panel expansion

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to place toggle buttons in description section of expansion panel. When they are interacted with the expansion panel reacts. How can I prevent expansion panel triggering when interacting with  toggle buttons? I provided and example here https://angular-ivy-he4grl.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event bubbles up to the panel header, to prevent this bubbling you can stop the propagation of the event with `event.stopPropagation()`. In your case i simply added a click event to each button as such:

```
<mat-button-toggle
  value="bold"
  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
>
    Bold
</mat-button-toggle>
```

Modified version of your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jjtcyj